# Why console.log.apply("some string") doesn't work?

Tags: javascript

Why `console.log.apply("some string")` doesn't work ?

Trying to apply the method `.log()` to some string or any other variable fails.

For example:

```
let x = 100;
console.log.apply(x); // doesn't display 100 !
```

Also, no matter what I use for that variable it doesn't work, either array or object.

```
let y = [100, 200];
let z = new Date();

console.log.apply(y); // doesn't display [100, 200]
console.log.apply([100, 200]); // doesn't display [100, 200] either

console.log.apply(z); // doesn't display the Date object
console.log.apply({car: "Ford", price: 25000}); // nothing, too
```

Comment: What are you trying to achieve by using [`apply`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply)? Why not call the method normally and pass `x`/`y`/`z` as an argument?

Comment: @Bergi Hope that reading my comment at the answer below will finally answer your question. Probably most helpful thing in stackoverflow for a question is to receive an informed answer (not another question and some downvotes, who knows :)). And I don't try to achieve something with *apply*, I just try to understand perfectly how *apply* works - that's what matters after all. I'm not a copy paste person and maybe never answer to someone asking me "how to do that in vs code" with stuff like "do it in notepad which is easier" - my purpose being to go up not down in knowledge ... peace!

Comment: If you want to understand how `apply` works, I suggest applying it to your own function (where you can inspect `this` and `arguments`) not to `console.log`

Comment: @Bergi if having a simple function as to extract the square root of a number, it would suffice an unique argument, no need for any ```this``` whatsoever. I tend to work on pure functions then create complex code structures from them. In programming as in real world perfection might be to not be able to remove anything more (simpler is better) - probably some simplicity similar to what jQuery shows on syntax. Square root function exists, I know, was just an example for an operation that only targets a single entity. 1/2

Comment: ```This``` is ilogically mentioned in ```apply``` because already you attach the ```apply``` with the dot connector ```.``` to some new ```this```, so really, nobody sees that ??? Am I missing something here maybe ? Initial ```firstObject.methodOne(argument)``` should just become ```someOther.methodOne.apply(newarg)``` 2/2

Comment: I'm not saying that you *need to use* `this`, but that you should inspect it to understand `apply`. You may not need it for pure functions, yet `apply` was not made for them but for arbitrary methods, and you still need to pass something (like `undefined`) for `apply`'s first argument if you want to use `apply`.

Comment: "*you attach the `apply` with the dot connector `.` to some new `this`*" - no you don't. You attach `apply` itself to the *method* (as `apply`'s `this` value), but then it's not clear what the method is attached to then (the `object`). `object.method()` is the same as `method.apply(object, [])`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/244374/discussion-between-eve-and-bergi).

Answer (score 2):

The first argument of `.apply` this the value of `this` from the context of the function being executed. The second argument is an array of values being passed as arguments to the function.
So you should pass the array as the second argument:

```js
console.log.apply(null, ["hello"]);
```

Further documentation can be found on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply)

Comment: I appreciate your answer. In my understanding, apply was used mainly to extend (or "hire") the original behavior / execution of a function (or method) to another context or owner (object). As such, I am not sure why the "null" is even needed. I can understand that having an array (second argument) even enriches even more the capabilities of the extended function (to work with even more args), but why couldn't entirely be left out the first one (it's null, after all, and not needed). To make a long story short, sometimes MDN is quite dry in regard of much needed thorough explanations. 1/2

Comment: and even here it's sometimes difficult to receive a full answer :) 2/2